# ElasticSearch: Java API from 2.x to 5.x issues

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm changing from ES 2.x java API to 5.x.

In 2.x I was used to do that in order to create an alias:

```
AliasAction action = new AliasAction(AliasAction.Type.ADD)
            .alias(username)
            .index(ElasticsearchRepository.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX)
            .searchRouting(username)
            .indexRouting(username)
            .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", username));

    request = request.addAliasAction(action);
```

I0ve tried to figure out how to move that on 5.x. Nevertheless, I don't quite  understand how to get that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here : https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.0.0

It seems like they changed the way to attribute the alias to something like this :

```
    IndicesAliasesRequest indicesAliasesRequest = new IndicesAliasesRequest();
    indicesAliasesRequest.addAliasAction(IndicesAliasesRequest.AliasActions.add()
                                       .alias("TheAliasToAdd")
                                       .index("TheIndexToAddTheAliasTo"));
    client.admin().indices().aliases(indicesAliasesRequest);
```